# Why does appending an element onto a YouTube chromeless div cause it to flash with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, api, youtube

I'm trying to append a `<div>` with some controls in it onto my chromeless youtube container with jQuery when a user hover's over the player, but it causes the player flash black and white.

```
$("#lol").appendTo("#ytplayerid");
```

I'm trying to go for a similar effect to this: http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/07/youtube-api-custom-player-jquery-css/youtube-player.html

Answer (score 0):

Could be something to do with z-index. Perhaps set the z-index on the player element to 1000 and then set it lower on the div. Be sure to set position on the elements to apply the z-index.

Comment: Hmm. Could you post a live example so we can see what's up?